Why does exrex produce a failing regex example?
exrex is a Python library that, when provided a regular expression (RE), produces example strings that satisfy that RE.
Normally it works well, but for this RE:
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,}$
, exrex produces example strings that do not validate against the RE.
Below is a script to reproduce the failure, along with another similar, but passing, RE.
Why does exrex fail for the above RE?
import re
import exrex

def test_re(re_str):
    test_str = exrex.getone(re_str)
    res = re.fullmatch(re_str, test_str)
    return res == True

# PASSES
assert test_re("^(    [A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,}$")

# FAILS
assert test_re("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,}$")


Why did people downvote my question?

The reason the second RE fails is that it contains a lookahead assertion:

A lookahead assertion "looks ahead": it attempts to match the
subsequent input with the given pattern, but it does not consume any
of the input — if the match is successful, the current position in the
input stays the same.

Specifically the expression ?=.* "looks ahead" to require that the subsequent expression [A-Za-z0-9]{6,} contain at least one letter [A-Za-z].  exrex.getone does not support lookahead assertions.
